# How to pause a timer Object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, time, android-lifecycle

I use this fragment of code in an activity to display a timer countdown:

```
//SET COUNTDOWN TIMER in onCreate()
     //var tempo is a :Long number

        var textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.countdownTimer)
        object : CountDownTimer(tempo, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                textView.setText("Remaining time: "+tim(millisUntilFinished) )
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                textView.text = "Times up!"
            }

        }.start()
```

If possible I'd like to implement the possibility to pause this CountDownTimer in **onBackPressed()** and resume it again?

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
            setTitle("Confirm")
            setMessage("Exit app?")

            setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                // if user press yes, cancel timer?
                super.onBackPressed()
            }

            setNegativeButton("No"){_, _ ->
                // if user press no, then return the activity and resume timer?
            }

            setCancelable(true)
        }.create().show()
    }
```

My idea would be to edit **var *tempo*** differentitate it everytime OnBackPressed and copy the section of this 1st code piece in onCreate() and put it onResume().

I'm quite confused on using this tbh. MAybe there's a faster and better way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pause `CountDownTimer`. What you can do is stop it and then start another one (with the remaining time) when you want to resume it.